# how to check if an element exists in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js object as below.

```
var t = { x: 0, y: 'string', v: 10000 };
```

my present code is.

```
if (!t.x || !t.y) {
    throw "x and y required";
}
```

My problem is in my code `x` can have the value `0` but if in that case I do a `!t.x`
then I get true.

How can I ensure that my data has `x` and `y` and also ensure that `x` can have the value `0`.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jo7vx4p/

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: or rather `"x" in t`. But it's a duplicate and a frequent question.

Answer (score 2):

The method your are looking for is:

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

e.g:

```
if(!t.hasOwnProperty('x') || !t.hasOwnProperty('y')) {

}
```

Comment: Or the ridiculously over-complex: `Object.keys(t).indexOf('x') === -1` (for the sake of a full answer, really, I would absolutely *not* recommend this approach ever...) :)

Comment: But the question was : How can I ensure that my data has x and y and also ensure that x can have the value 0 ? With your code x and y could be undefined and will pass the test. I would check x and y to be a number too.

Comment: I need x and y to have proper values , they can not be null or undefined

Comment: @Arnab - sounds like you'll need `Number.isNaN` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN. `if(Number.isNaN(t.x) || Number.isNaN(t.y)) { throw new Error(...) }`

Comment: @Adam thanx but y is string, is there something for string which will handle null and undefined